# Is there a good pattern to extract data from a map?

Tags: c++, stdmap, bigdata

I am working with c++ to process data and create various histograms for them. The histogram definitions are stored in a json file which I read in and convert into a "histogram name(std::string) to histogram object(histogram object)" map.

I pass this map later to an object whose purpose is to fill these histograms with data. However I cant use the histogram objects there as a map, because it is rather slow to look up every single histogram in it by a string identifier. Because of this, the class holds on to instances of pointers to every single histogram it requires to fill. The performance does not suffer this way and this speeds up the running time quite a lot. However, to do this I need to write a lot of what I consider garbage code.

The histogram declarations are necessary, but can I somehow improve the readability of the extraction from the map?

Right now the mentioned part has a few hundred lines like this:

```
sensorEfficiencyWithCutsPhiVsZ_l4  = checkGetHistoFromMap("sensorEfficiencyWithCutsPhiVsZ_l4");
sensorEfficiencyWithCutsPhiVsZ_fwd = checkGetHistoFromMap("sensorEfficiencyWithCutsPhiVsZ_fwd");
rechitPhiVsZ_l1                    = checkGetHistoFromMap("rechitPhiVsZ_l1");
rechitPhiVsZ_l2                    = checkGetHistoFromMap("rechitPhiVsZ_l2");
rechitPhiVsZ_l3                    = checkGetHistoFromMap("rechitPhiVsZ_l3");
rechitPhiVsZ_l4                    = checkGetHistoFromMap("rechitPhiVsZ_l4");
rechitPhiVsZ_fwd                   = checkGetHistoFromMap("rechitPhiVsZ_fwd");
vtxNtrkNumhitsPreCuts              = checkGetHistoFromMap("vtxNtrkNumhitsPreCuts");
vtxNtrkEfficiencyPreCuts           = checkGetHistoFromMap("vtxNtrkEfficiencyPreCuts");
nMinus1VtxNtrkNumhits              = checkGetHistoFromMap("nMinus1VtxNtrkNumhits");
nMinus1VtxNtrkEfficiency           = checkGetHistoFromMap("nMinus1VtxNtrkEfficiency");
nMinus1PtNumhits                   = checkGetHistoFromMap("nMinus1PtNumhits");
nMinus1PtEfficiency                = checkGetHistoFromMap("nMinus1PtEfficiency");
```

Can I somehow shorten this to something like this:

```
std::vector<HistogramPointerType> histograms = { long list of histogram names };
std::for_each(histograms.begin(); histograms.end(), [this] (HistogramType histogram) 
{
     this -> (name of the histogram) = checkGetHistoFromMap((name of histogram as converted to string));
});
```

Or is there any other way to shorten this repetitive listing?

Comment: How does `checkGetHistoFromMap` work?

Comment: You current code has a direct association of a member with a string, the code you want puts the two lists in separate places where the synchronisation of order of both lists will count thus improving the chance for errors. Your current version is better.

Comment: @AlexanderLapenkov just gets the address of the element if it exists and if it doesn't then it handles the exception thrown for map.at().

Comment: You seem to be asking to store the property name and string literal together.  AFAIK, this would need some weird `#define`s, and isn't ideal.  If most or all of the few hundred histograms will be processed in the same manner, you can consider keeping all the histograms in a `map`, `vector` or fixed-length array instead of giving every histogram a different name.